# Git Bash can't change directory to documents folder

Tags: git

I'm trying to following this Github tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73I5dRucCds
When I try to change my directory to my desktop, I get this in my Git Shell:

```
Natha_000@idea-PC MINGW64 ~ 
$ cd /desktop
bash: cd: /desktop: No such file or directory

Natha_000@idea-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cd /Desktop
bash: cd: /Desktop: No such file or directory

Natha_000@idea-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cd Desktop
bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory

Natha_000@idea-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cd Documents
bash: cd: Documents: No such file or directory

Natha_000@idea-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cd /c/Desktop
bash: cd: /c/Desktop: No such file or directory

Natha_000@idea-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cd Documents
bash: cd: Documents: No such file or directory
```

I've tried a few different things and It doesn't seem to work. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?
I'm guessing it's going to be a pretty stupid mistake...

Comment: Try `ls` or `pwd` to see the possibilities you have

I don't use git bash, but I see it opens in `/c/Users/<username>/` so probably `cd /c/Users/<your username>/Desktop` will work

Answer (score 15):

It seems to me you are trying to understand where `Documents` is.

To do that open your terminal and type `cd`, that will change your current directory to your home folder.

Once in your home, which should look like `/c/Users/YOUR-USERNAME`, type `ls`, your `Documents` folder is there.

tl;dr `cd /c/Users/YOUR-USERNAME/Documents`.

Comment: That worked. I knew it was something stupid. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$ cd C:/Users/(YOURUSERNAME)/Desktop
```

If you are not sure what your username is, then try

```
$ cd C:/Users
```

Then this to see what options are available

```
$ ls
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Directory/Folder where you want to go .Right Click inside that folder and there will be an option called as Git Bash here. click on it .Then a terminal will open with the path of that directory .

Answer (score 2):

The home directory of cygwin based apps like babun, git-bash, mobaxterm etc. i.e. ~ or $HOME is not the same as windows.

Windows user path is in the %USERPROFILE% environment variable which in cygwin syntax is /c/Users/YOURUSER (or /cygdrive/c/Users/YOURUSER), like pointed out by the other answers.

Also, Cygwin based apps handle HOME if it is already set to a custom path in Windows, see the Cygwin FAQ page: https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.home

Answer (score 0):

If you run `pwd` (print working directory) you'll know where you are in your system's file structure and navigate from there.

Assuming you're on Mac OS X you probably want to do `cd ~/Desktop` (`~` is a shorthand way of getting to your home folder).

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue,
try:

pwd

-to check which directory git is looking at

if it shows " \ "

type:

cd ~

-to change directory to home,

-after that you can continue to cd to your desired directory,

hope this works, PS this is my first contribution in Stack Overflow (excuse the formatting).