# Git-bash: cannot cd to My Documents

Tags: bash, windows-7, git-bash

I'm using git-bash on Windows 7 and it seems to work fine except that I cannot go to "My Documents". I found a slightly related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626377/git-bash-cant-change-directory-to-documents-folder), but it is in fact not my problem.

I tried to describe my problem in the screenshot below:
[image: cannot cd to My Documents]

Any help would be nice.

Comment: There is no "Documents" folder in your profile directory. I don't think Explorer updates the "My Documents" compatibility junction when the target is relocated. Right-click the Documents folder in Explorer, open the properties dialog, and click on the Location tab to see its real location on disk. You can create a new junction using `mklink /j junction target`.

Comment: @eryksun  Indeed, that was the problem. 'My Documents' is in fact the directory  d:/personal/jerome.cholewa  (without "My Documents"). Thanks!  It looks like mklink is not available directly in my install of git-bash, but `cmd //c 'mklink /j junction target'` would work.  How can i accept your answer (can't find the button..)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pulling @eryksun's comment into a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/147573) answer*

> There is no "Documents" folder in your profile directory. I don't think Explorer updates the "My Documents" compatibility junction when the target is relocated. Right-click the Documents folder in Explorer, open the properties dialog, and click on the Location tab to see its real location on disk. You can create a new junction using `mklink /j junction target`.

Comment: It can happens in company polocy to relocate the "Documents" folder on network. in my company it looked like "\\companyServer\companyUsersFolder\myUser" or with / on bash prompt.